# Why is there a computation error when returning function with structure

Tags: c, function, date, struct, arguments

I am trying to find the number of elapsed days between two dates. However, with some dates the program prints the wrong number of days between 2 dates.

The formula for number of elapsed days is: N=1461 x f(year,month) / 4+ 153 x g(month)/5 +day

In my program, I have f and g defined as functions that return different values of years and months depending on what the user inputs.

The main problem probably lies with how I scanned the user input with the local variables in the date structure.

N1 is the number of elapsed days for the 1st date. N2 is for the second date.

Below is my written code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct date {
        int month;
        int day;
        int year;
    };

int f( int theyear,  int themonth){
    if (themonth <=2)
        theyear = theyear-1;
    else
        theyear =theyear; 
    return theyear;
}

int g( int Month){
    if (Month<=2)
        Month=Month+13;
    else 
        Month = Month+1;

    return Month;
}

int main()

{

    struct date time1, time2;
    int N1; int N2;



    printf("Enter time1 (mm,dd,yyyy): ");
    scanf("%i%i%i", &time1.month, &time1.day, &time1.year);

    printf("Enter time2 (mm,dd,yyyy): ");
    scanf("%i%i%i", &time2.month, &time2.day, &time2.year);
    N1=1461 * f(time1.year,time1.month) / 4 + 153 * g(time2.month) / 5 +3;
    N2 = 1461 * f(time2.year,time2.month)/4 +153 * g(time2.month)/5 +21;



    printf("%d \n",abs(N1 -N2));

    return 0;

}
```

Thank you very much. :)

Sample input/output:

Enter time1 (mm,dd,yyyy): 04 10 1994
Enter time2 (mm,dd,yyyy): 03 10 1994
18

As you can see, it prints out 18. However, it is supposed to be the number of days in a month.

Comment: Sample input and output please.

Comment: Tell your users to avoid certain date combinations and call it a "feature". Then, after fixing it, you can advertise it as having "new features!!" Or .. give some examples.

Comment: Did you try to *debug* your problem?

Comment: Sure I provided input/output! And I'm not sure if that would work Jongware, I'm just trying to make sure my program fully works.

Comment: What are the equations for `f()` and `g()`?

Comment: so for f the parameters are f(year,month) if the month is less or equal to 2 then we subtract 1 from the year. otherwise(else) we just return the year.For g if month is <= 2 then we add 13 to the month. otherwise, we just add 1 to month. The purpose of this is for calculating the number of days for the equation .

Comment: @XiJiaopin Where did you get this equation?  Online?

Comment: From a book to be specific. But I am sure that the equation is valid, so the problem doesn't lie there!

Comment: Order of operation seems to matter.  The equation uses C's precedence and associativity rules?

Comment: @XiJiaopin: That formula will work if the two dates are both between March 1, 1900 and February 28, 2100. That might be safe for your problem domain, but it is not really a general formula; it will fail if the date range includes the non-existent leap day in a century not divisible by 400.

Answer (score 3):

change

```
N1=1461 * f(time1.year,time1.month) / 4 + 153 * g(time2.month) / 5 +3;
N2 =1461 * f(time2.year,time2.month)/4 +153 * g(time2.month)/5 +21;
```

to

```
N1=1461 * f(time1.year,time1.month) / 4 + 153 * g(time1.month) / 5 + time1.day;
N2 =1461 * f(time2.year,time2.month)/4 +153 * g(time2.month)/5 + time2.day;
```

?

Comment: How did you figure that out?  Good job!

Comment: Lol, was wondering why he has a +3 for N1 and a +21 for N2, then referring back to the formula, it should be the days instead of a fixed number